# "End of script output before headers: bot.wsgi" and "Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2" error with Flask and Apache2

Tags: python, apache, ubuntu, flask, segmentation-fault

I'm getting the following errors and stuck for days.

```
[Fri Jul 29 01:50:42.893072 2016] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 13065:tid 139798263351168] AH00489: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.0.1f mod_wsgi/3.4 Python/2.7.6 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Fri Jul 29 01:50:42.893205 2016] [core:notice] [pid 13065:tid 139798263351168] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Fri Jul 29 01:50:48.564383 2016] [core:error] [pid 13070:tid 139798144440064][client 183.96.207.33:57918] End of script output before headers: fb_bot.wsgi
[Fri Jul 29 01:50:48.899034 2016] [core:notice] [pid 13065:tid 139798263351168] AH00051: child pid 13068 exit signal Segmentation fault (11), possible coredump in /etc/apache2
```

I'm deploying a Flask app(python) on ubuntu using Apache2 and aws.

the below is fb_bot.wsgi file

```
1 import sys
2 sys.path.insert(0,'/home/ubuntu/Findabot/fb_bot')
3 from fb_bot import app as application
```

as you can see, nothing special. I also tried adding shebang

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

at the first line of the wsgi file but still got the same error.

I really really need help. any suggestions??

**EDIT1:**

I commented out the code below

```
kkma = Kkma()
```

and I did not get the error. Kkma is a class comes with koNLPy library, which uses JVM. Would this be a reason? I do not have any workaround not to use this library. What should I do?